# Please confirm units in this sendTransaction are reasonable

Tags: go-ethereum, console

Can you please double-check this command for me and tell me if I screwed up the units?

```
eth.sendTransaction({ from: "blah", to: "blah", value:20000000000000000, nonce:5, gas:120000, gasPrice:80000000000 })
```

I had a little panic attack afterward about whether I was supposed to put `gasPrice` in wei or gwei.  I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) and it says wei, but nevertheless I'd like the peace of mind of a second set of eyes.

If one screws it up and puts in a ridiculously high gas price beyond the available funds, will that burn up all of what's remaining in the account before it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `web3.toWei` to easily convert amounts to wei from other units

```
eth.sendTransaction({
    from: "blah",
    to: "blah",
    value: web3.toWei(0.02, "ether"),
    nonce: 5,
    gas: 120000,
    gasPrice: web3.toWei(80, "gwei")
});
```

Also useful is `web.fromWei` to convert from wei to other units

```
> web3.fromWei("80000000000", "gwei");
"80"
> web3.fromWei("20000000000000000", "ether");
"0.02"
```

Comment: Thanks; this is very helpful!  So my values were reasonable?  i.e. My gasPrice was 80 gwei and I was sending 0.02 eth?  What happens if you screw up and use a ballistic gas price either within or outside the means of your account balance?  Does anything protect you from a typo with extra zeroes recklessly burning through all your account funds?

Comment: Gas price is a dynamic value, sometime during a popular ICO the cost goes up. You can use http://ethgasstation.info/ to determine the convenient price at given moment, ie how much time can you wait for a  transaction to be mined vs the price you want to pay. A good wallet can calculate the total of a transaction, but otherwise if you have enough funds there's nothing that can save you if you put too many zeros in the gas price.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question.  Ethgasstation.info was down at the time so I just looked at gas prices of recent transactions on Etherscan.io and added a nice fat margin.

Comment: web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"). (*web3 updates)

Comment: @EHM It is a 5 years old answer! It was for web3 v0.20.xx. I'd suggest to add an new answer with the updates for web3 v1.xx.

Answer (score 0):

**Version updates**

As of the current version of web3 (v1.xx) the toWei function has been moved to web3.utils, so instead of `web3.toWei(0.02, "ether")`, you want to do `web3.utils.toWei(0.02, "ether")`. For more, check [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#towei).